# AJAX response always 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I try to develop a wordpress plugin.
Now I want to make a AJAX call.

I've two files.

First file is the file of my template:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'dmd_action_javascript' );
?>

<?php function dmd_action_javascript() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //click event f�r submit button
  jQuery('.dmd_admin_button').click(function () {

  //Daten von den HTML Feldern in JS-Vars �bersetzen
  var post = jQuery('input[name=dmd_fast_post]');
  var page = jQuery('input[name=dmd_fast_page]');
  var searchbox = jQuery('input[name=dmd_fast_searchbox]');
  var formidable = jQuery('input[name=dmd_fast_formidable]');
  var key = jQuery('input[name=dmd_fast_key]');

  if ( jQuery( post ).prop( "checked" ) )
      post.val(1); 
  else
      post.val(0);

 if ( jQuery( page ).prop( "checked" ) )
     page.val(1);
 else
     page.val(0);

  if ( jQuery( searchbox ).prop( "checked" ) )
     searchbox.val(1);
 else
     searchbox.val(0);

  if ( jQuery( formidable ).prop( "checked" ) )
     formidable.val(1);
 else
     formidable.val(0);     

  var data = 'post=' + post.val() + '&page=' + page.val() + '&searchbox=' + searchbox.val() + '&formidable=' + formidable.val() + '&key=' + key.val();
jQuery.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: ajaxurl, // our PHP handler file
      data: { action: "my_backend_action", data:data },
      success:function(data){
            alert(data);
      },
      error: function(errorThrown){
          alert(errorThrown);
      } 

  });
return false;      

    });
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

my second file in my plugin should response some values of the AJAX call.:

```
    public function set_actions(){
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'dmd_custom_style_load'), 99 ); 
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'dmd_enqueue_child_theme_styles'), 99);
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, 'dmd_register_adminmenu'));
        add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', array($this, 'dmdPages'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_my_backend_action_callback', array($this, 'my_backend_action_callback'));
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_backend_action_callback', array($this, 'my_backend_action_callback'));
    } 

public function my_backend_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval($_POST['data']);

    echo $whatever;
    exit(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

Sorry, but I read all questions and answers in stackoverflow and nothing helps me.

I can't find my fault. Can somebody tell me what is the issue?

EDIT:

In firebug my post looks like this:

> action    my_backend_action data
>   post=1&page=1&searchbox=0&formidable=0&key=27dda19e85378bb8df73fa3f2806a30c

Comment: You have `jQuery( post ).prop( "checked" )` and `post` is already defined as a `jQuery` object. So you need just `post.prop('checked')`

Comment: In firebug the post ist correct. I edit my question.

Comment: And what is "data" in the post? You are converting it to an int?? but it is a string??

Comment: are you getting proper value of `ajaxurl` ?

Comment: Ah you are right. If I do ech 'test' I get response: 'test'.

Comment: echo $_POST[data] will output my whole post data.. perfect. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                data: {"action": "validateID","post": post.val(), "page": page.val() , "searchbox": searchbox.val(), "formidable": formidable.val(), "key": key.val()},
                success: function(data){
                     alert(data);
    }
});
```

*Call ajax as above amd then write following and see now print anything or not*

```
function validateID(){
    echo $response = $_REQUEST['post'];
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_validateID', 'validateID' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_validateID', 'validateID' );
```

Comment: That is the perfect answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a string that looks like a querystring. And you are trying go convert that string to an int. That is your problem.

When you do

```
var data = 'post=' + post.val() + '&page=' + page.val() + '&searchbox=' + searchbox.val() + '&formidable=' + formidable.val() + '&key=' + key.val();`
```

You are building a single string and when you do

```
data: { action: "my_backend_action", data:data },
```

you are assigning that single string to the key data. The "parameters" you are trying to set wit post, page, etc, will not be accessible on the server.

Now on the server you are trying to read "data" and convert it to an integer.

```
$whatever = intval($_POST['data']);
```

I am not sure how you expect a string like `"post=1&page=1&searchbox=0"` to be converted to an int.

Your best bet is to not build a querystring yourself, but just build an object.

```
var data = { 
    post : post.val(),
    page : page.val(),
    searchbox : searchbox.val()
    formidable : formidable.val(),
    key : key.val(),
    action: "my_backend_action";
}
jQuery.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: ajaxurl, // our PHP handler file
      data: data,
      ...
```

Now on the server, get rid of that "data" and reference  post, page, key, etc.